# The init script to several Unicorn.rb instance

Tags: ruby, deployment, thin, unicorn

I use now thin to serve my rack application on my webserver. I have a lot of web application so I have a init script who check all file in my `/etc/thin` and start all of then with configuration inside.

I want migrate to unicorn so I want same behaviour, but when I check the example in unicorn, I found only init script to start one unicorn instance.

What I can use like init script to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was looking for the same thing. You'll need to create an init script for each app. I modified this init.d script which uses a PID file instead of the program name:

http://gist.github.com/308216